# Python regex takes for ever on large data

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to capture codes and stack traces from a file with free text. The idea is to classify codes from regular English language sentences.

These are the regex to capture different patterns so far.

```
[Cc][Cc]\[\\?"?\S+"?\\?\]
\w+\((\\?"?(((\w)+(.|:)?)+)*\\?"?,?\s?)*\)
(\w+\d*).?(?:<=?|>=?|==?|!=).*
\w+\/\d.?(\d)+\s?(\(.+\))?
\w+(\s|\.)?\w+\(((\w+,?\s?)?((\.)+)*)?\)
(\w+\/?)+[a-z\-]+\.?(h|cpp|c|java|py|html|css|js)\:
```

The python code compiles the patterns and match against each sentence in an object. Some objects have small number of lines (eg: ~30) while some have a large number of lines (eg: >200).

```
import re
import os

from models.Sentence import Sentence
from controllers.TextCleanController import TextCleanController

class SyntaxController:
    """Capture syntax in a sentence
    """
    def __init__(self):
        curr_dir = os.getcwd()
        pattern_file_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, "data", "regex.txt")

        patterns = list()
        with open(pattern_file_path) as f:
            patterns = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

        self.all_patterns = re.compile('|'.join(pat for pat in patterns))

    def findSyntax(self, sentence):
        """Find sentences that contain URL(s) and add a tag URL
        Parameters
        ----------
        sentences : obj
            Sentence object
        """


        tcc = TextCleanController()
        sentence.set_cleaned_text(tcc.clean_sentence(sentence.get_text(), r_digit=False, r_punc=False, lem=False, stop=False))

        if self.all_patterns.search(sentence.get_cleaned_text()):
            if 'C' not in sentence.get_tags():
                sentence.add_a_tag('C')
```

`Sentence` is a model in my program and the `TextCleanController` is used to clean the text.

I wondering what I am doing wrong here as this takes forever on large files.

Here are a few sample data I'm trying to detect with tag **C**.

```
error_550_is_directory (FtpConnection *conn, const FtpFile *file)
{
    guint response = ftp_connection_send (conn,  RESPONSE_PASS_500, \"cwd %s\", file);
    if (response == 550)
    {
        g_set_error (&amp;conn-&amp;gt;error, G_IO_ERROR,  G_IO_ERROR_IS_DIRECTORY, _(\"File is a directory\"));
    }
}
```

over an actual English language sentence as follows.

```
The patch gets the gist of what I want, but it looks ugly in places.
```

Comment: See [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Narrow down to which regex.. Then fix

Answer (score 1):

You're prone to catastrophic backtracking, usually quantifiers inside quantifiers. In your case

```
(\\?"?(((\w)+(.|:)?)+)*\\?"?,?\s?)*\)
                     ^^^         ^^^
```

Besides, the expression looks like it can be vastly optimized.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment and an answer.

It's difficult to answer your problem since you provided a couple of regex and no sample data.

However, I can point few improvements that might help on the performance:

```
[Cc][Cc]\[\\?"?\S+"?\\?\] ===> (?i)[c]{2}\[\\?"?\S+"?\\?\]

\w+\/\d.?(\d)+\s?(\(.+\))? ===> \w+\/\d.?\d+\s?(\(.+\))?
         ^^^^---- avoid capturing repetaedly groups

\w+(\s|\.)?\w+\(((\w+,?\s?)?((\.)+)*)?\) ===> \w+[\s\.]?\w+\(((\w+,?\s?)?\.+)?\)
   ^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^
      |                          +--- this generate terrible performance
      +--- use character classes when matching once
```

This regex has terrible backtracking as well:

```
\w+\((\\?"?(((\w)+(.|:)?)+)*\\?"?,?\s?)*\)
```

I think you can use `\w+\((\\?"?(\w+[.:]?)+\\?"?,?\s?)*\)`

Comment: I replaced the regex with yours. Still could make a decent performance. However, I understood the poor regex I wrote. Let me do a further investigation with the new regex.

Comment: @akalanka glad to read it improved. The performance leaks are the parts where you have quantifiers inside quantifiers like this `((\.)+)*)?` which generates a problem named "catastrophic backtracking". So, you can replace this `((\.)+)*)?` with `\.*` because at the end it generates the same match

Answer (score 1):

Try these.
The next to last one is troubling and is probable culprit.

`[Cc][Cc]\[\\?"?\S+"?\\?\]` replace to `[Cc][Cc]\[\S+?\]`

`\w+\((\\?"?(((\w)+(.|:)?)+)*\\?"?,?\s?)*\)` replace to `\w+\((\\?"?(\w+[.:]?)*\\?"?,?\s?)*\)`

`(\w+\d*).?(?:<=?|>=?|==?|!=).*` replace to `(\w+)\.?(?:[<>=]=?|!=).*`

`\w+\/\d.?(\d)+\s?(\(.+\))?` replace to `\w+\/\d\.?(\d+)\s?(\(.+?\))?`

`\w+(\s|\.)?\w+\(((\w+,?\s?)?((\.)+)*)?\)` replace to `\w+([\s.])?\w+\((\w+,?\s?[.]*|[.]+)?\)`

`(\w+\/?)+[a-z\-]+\.?(h|cpp|c|java|py|html|css|js)\:` replce to `(\w+\/?)+[a-z-]+\.?(h|cpp|c|java|py|html|css|js):`

Comment: The last pattern that map file extensions `h|cpp|c|java|py|html|css|js` is giving me trouble. It works better for my test cases. But not for actual data.

Comment: File ext (last rx) just taken out 2 escapes, otherwise it yurs. I don't understend whet yuo try to do it with. l

Comment: It just seems having multiple file extensions in the regex is a bad idea. I changed it to check only .c and .h files. Maybe I have to have separate regex to each file extension instead of using a pipe (`|`). It just a thought. I don't have any evidence supporting my case.